# Auto-generate interface methods in Java with Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ide, code-completion

Using the [Red Hat Java extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) I can see a list of unimplemented methods, but there is no "auto-generate" button that I can find. Does this functionality exist?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a Java-IDE like eclipse or IntelliJ? Anyway, this is a legitimate question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this post:
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/270 , you can put your cursor on the class name and then press the shortcut "⌘.".

Comment: You can also click the bulb on the left side instead of using the shortcut.